# Copy and Paste Largest value in a column from one workbook to another

Tags: vba

I am attempting to first, find the the largest value in a column (C), then copy and paste that value into the next empty cell in 'Row 3' in a different (master) workbook.  The macro I am running is found in the master workbook. I found this code that i believe will get the pasted cell into the correct spot, but I could use assistance in the code for how to find the largest cell in column C in the data workbook, and then copying and pasting that value.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, wbDATA As Workbook
Dim NextColumn As Long, LastRow As Long

Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contract Metrics")
NextColumn = wsMaster.Range("C", 3).End(xlUp).Column + 1

Set wbDATA = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\Michael Palkovitz\My Documents\Test\Contracts Metrics.xlsx")

wbDATA.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered using a formula in the master workbook that refers to the other workbook? Then you will not need VBA at all. There are a whole host of issues in doing that (security and stability being just two), but it might be appropriate to your specific requirement.

Comment: We considered this but my boss prefers we do it through vba so it is one click and the data is pulled into the correct cell and there are less security issues

Comment: I found a code that I think fits part of what I am trying to do, which is what was updated from the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  First sort the column you need the value from, then get the last row and place the value into your first empty column in row 3 of your master sheet.

```
' Create an excel application and open the workbook containing the data
Dim app As Object
Dim wb As Object
Dim ws As Object

Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\Workbook1")
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

' Get last row with a value to use for the sort range
Dim last As Long
Dim value As Long
With ws
    last = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row
    .Range("C1:C" & last).Sort Key1:=.Range("C2"), order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

    value = .Cells(last, 3)
End With

' Get the last filled cell and move over one to get the empty column

Dim col As Long
col = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Column

ActiveSheet.Cells(3, col).value = value

wb.Close False
Set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set app = Nothing
```